# Какую библиотеку js выбрать для визуализации работы

Tags: javascript, c#, frontend, backend

Есть backend (C#), из которого я буду получать данные: список объектов Edge, где есть свойство double[][] Coordinates, в котором задаются точки координатами. Так же список объектов Spot, в котором также присутствуют координаты точки. Мне нужно визуализировать это все в 3d, примерно как это должно выглядеть показал на картинке. Мне подсказали что лучше нужно от бэка получать json со всеми данными и потом на фронте визуализировать это с помощью какой-нибудь библиотеки JS. Я не слишком хорошо знаю JS, поэтому хотел чтобы вы мне подсказали какую библиотеку юзать, желательно под лицензией MIT. И желательно чтобы в которую было легко вкатиться)
[image: Пример]

Comment: судя по координатам - они двумерные - как их можно визуализировать в 3d?

Comment: @Grundy нет, они трехмерные xyz. Просто картинка как пример такая (не моя, самому прислали).

Comment: `double[][] Coordinates` - это двумерный массив, то есть в нем хранятся только два значения, а не три, для трехмерных координат

Comment: @Grundy там чуть чуть не так. double[0][0] это x. double[0][1] это y. double[0][2] это z. double[1]... это вторая точка и т.д.

Comment: В итоге, что именно ты хочешь отрисовать? И линии красно/зеленые точки?

Comment: @Grundy да по сути. Нужно отрисовать вертикальные грани, которые заданы четырьмя точками координатами xyz. И так же некоторые точки - сетку, в которой точка либо красная либо зеленая, зависит от условия.

Comment: В принципе это можно сделать напрямую с canvas без библиотек вообще

Comment: @Grundy а что насчет Cesium JS? Или что то вроде QGis?

Comment: Все зависит от сложности картинки, если она вида как на картинке в вопросе, скорее всего проще будет руками чем разбираться с библиотеками